# Deserializing into a List without a container that contains one more list

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I need to deserialize such structure using XmlSerializer.

```
  <root>   
    <parameter1>
    5
    </parameter1>
    <itemList>
      <parameter2>5</parameter2>
      <item>v</item>
      <item>v2</item>
    </itemList>
    <itemList>
      <parameter2>50</parameter2>
      <item>v3</item>
      <item>v4</item>
    </itemList>
  </root>
```

Using this code:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("parameter1")]
    public List<ItemList> Parameter1{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("itemList")]
    public List<ItemList> ItemLists{ get; set; }
}

public class ItemList
{
    [XmlElement("parameter2")]
    public List<ItemList> Parameter2{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("item")]
    public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}
```

but it desirialize only 1 element on each level.
If I use such objects:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("parameter1")]
    public List<ItemList> Parameter1{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("itemList")]
    public List<ItemList> ItemLists{ get; set; }
}

public class ItemList
{
    [XmlElement("parameter2")]
    public List<ItemList> Parameter2{ get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}
```

it deserialize all ItemList objects, but Item list is empty.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa(v=vs.110).aspx

I don't think the serializer can understand this structure:

```
<root>   
  <parameter1>
  5
  </parameter1>
  <itemList>
    <parameter2>5</parameter2>
    <item>v</item>
    <item>v2</item>
  </itemList>
  <itemList>
  <parameter2>50</parameter2>
    <item>v3</item>
    <item>v4</item>
  </itemList>
</root>
```

what you should try instead is something like that:

```
<root>   
  <parameter1>
  5
  </parameter1>
  <itemLists>
    <itemList>
      <parameter2>5</parameter2>
      <items>
        <item>
          <parameter3>v</parameter3>
        </item>
        <item>
          <parameter3>v2</parameter3>
        </item>
      </items>
    </itemList>
    <itemList>
      <parameter2>50</parameter2>
      <items>
        <item>
          <parameter3>v3</parameter3>
        </item>
        <item>
          <parameter3>v4</parameter3>
        </item>
      </items>
    </itemList>
  </itemLists>
</root>
```

This would be represented by following classes:

```
[XmlRoot("root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("parameter1")]
    public int Parameter1{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("itemLists")]
    public List<ItemList> ItemLists{ get; set; }
}

public class ItemList
{
    [XmlElement("parameter2")]
    public List<ItemList> Parameter2{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("items")]
    public List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("parameter3")]
    public string Parameter3{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, using v..v4 I mean structured object. SO this doesn`t work too.